# RepositoryRestResource with spring-boot CLI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to implement a simple REST service based on a JPA repository with spring-boot and spring-data-rest. (see this [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)) The following code works quite well if a use it with gradle:

```
package ch.bfh.swos.bookapp

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
import javax.persistence.*

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run Application, args
    }
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "authors")
interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id
    private String firstname
    private String lastname
}
```

To make things even simpler i tried the same code with the spring boot CLI ("spring run" command).

```
package ch.bfh.swos.bookapp

@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
@Grab("h2")

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

import javax.persistence.*

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "authors")
interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id
    private String firstname
    private String lastname
}
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. @RepositoryRestResource seems not to be automatically recognized like e.g. @RestController.
Leaving the @Configuration part in, the server starts up, but the REST repository is not created as if it would with gradle.

Does anybody know if it is possible to create a RepositoryRestResource with the spring-boot CLI and how the correct code should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a class definition to hang the `@Import` from (the other annotations that go on a class and not an interface are redundant).

Update: *and* (more importantly) Hibernate can't find your annotated classes unless they are actually in a file (it analyzes the byte code not the class definition reflectively). So you can make you app work by jarring it up and running it that way:

```
$ spring jar app.jar app.groovy
$ java -jar app.jar
```

Here's a shorter version of the app that works like that with all the redundant stuff removed:

```
package bookapp

@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
@Grab("h2")

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

import javax.persistence.*

@Configuration
class App {}  

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "authors")
interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {}

@Entity
class Author {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id
  String firstname
  String lastname
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add @Import to a class (the application class). But unfortunately the Spring Boot CLI creates it's own application class (as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#cli-automatic-main-method) ). Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to customize the application class so I could add my own import statements.

Comment: Thanks for your patience ;-). Tried it with an App class but that doesn't work too. See my following "answer" for the new (not working) code and log.

Comment: Hey cool! That worked! Then the problem wasn't Spring Boot not finding the Spring Data REST annotations but Hibernate not finding the Entity annotation until the code is compiled. I can live with that. Thx very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dave I tried to add the @Import statement to a class "App". The code now looks like this.

```
package ch.bfh.swos.bookapp

@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
@Grab("spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
@Grab("h2")

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

import javax.persistence.*

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class App {}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "authors")
interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id
    private String firstname
    private String lastname
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work too. The Spring Data Rest seems to get initialized correctly but the RepositoryRestResource is just ignored. Calling localhost:8080 just shows { }.
Any further suggestions?

Here the output of the Spring Boot log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.5.RELEASE)

2014-09-03 10:24:09.061  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on MIMA-WS-00 with PID 6264 (C:\development\maven\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar started by rovi in C:\Users\rovi\Desktop\springboot)
2014-09-03 10:24:09.261  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@62149bcb: startup date [Wed Sep 03 10:24:09 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-09-03 10:24:10.248  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2014-09-03 10:24:10.502  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jpaMapppingContext': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension$JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension$JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2014-09-03 10:24:11.293  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e485a8b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-09-03 10:24:11.331  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-09-03 10:24:11.346  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-09-03 10:24:11.359  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-09-03 10:24:11.879  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2014-09-03 10:24:12.045  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-09-03 10:24:12.049  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
2014-09-03 10:24:12.212  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader  : Unknown loader org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader@19d59bb2 class org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader$DefaultScopeParentClassLoader
2014-09-03 10:24:12.222  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-09-03 10:24:12.223  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2965 ms
2014-09-03 10:24:14.121  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-09-03 10:24:14.133  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2014-09-03 10:24:14.233  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
2014-09-03 10:24:14.237  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2014-09-03 10:24:14.239  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014-09-03 10:24:14.455  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
2014-09-03 10:24:14.546  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2014-09-03 10:24:14.640  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-09-03 10:24:14.826  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2014-09-03 10:24:14.835  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2014-09-03 10:24:15.437  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-09-03 10:24:15.440  INFO 6264 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2014-09-03 10:24:15.943  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2014-09-03 10:24:15.944  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2014-09-03 10:24:15.947  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2014-09-03 10:24:15.950  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2014-09-03 10:24:15.953  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2014-09-03 10:24:15.954  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2014-09-03 10:24:15.957  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/schema],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/schema+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2014-09-03 10:24:15.960  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.960  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.961  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.961  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource<?>,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.962  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.962  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.963  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.966  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.966  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2014-09-03 10:24:15.968  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2014-09-03 10:24:15.970  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2014-09-03 10:24:15.970  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2014-09-03 10:24:15.970  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2014-09-03 10:24:15.971  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2014-09-03 10:24:15.971  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2014-09-03 10:24:16.214  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-09-03 10:24:16.281  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2014-09-03 10:24:16.281  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2014-09-03 10:24:16.300  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-09-03 10:24:16.300  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-09-03 10:24:16.530  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-09-03 10:24:16.658  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
2014-09-03 10:24:16.661  INFO 6264 --- [       runner-0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 7.952 seconds (JVM running for 10.109)
2014-09-03 10:24:27.951  INFO 6264 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-09-03 10:24:27.952  INFO 6264 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2014-09-03 10:24:27.974  INFO 6264 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 22 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am late but please check if below helps you.

I have one working example and blog that uses RepositoryRestResource and EntityLinks.  Please check if this helps you.  On the blog you will find GitHub link too.

http://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2015/11/spring-boot-and-repositoryrestresource.html