# spring data RepositoryRestResource not being mapped to endpoints in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I've been trying to set up a rest service using spring data rest and spring boot. I followed the tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ but the expected rest endpoints were not created on startup, and calling get methods on them only led to a 404. I can create an endpoint with RestController, but not with RepositoryRestResource. I am using Spring Boot 2 and hibernate 5.2, with postgres as the backing datastore. I am using eclipse, and have tried running the application via Run Java Application in eclipse, as well as running it from the windows command line using java -jar. The output and end result is the same. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do for the expected endpoints to be created by the RepositoryRestResource? I've put example code below, with the spring boot output at the bottom, but first here are some similar questions and what I've tried:

this question has an accepted answer which seems to suggest its an entity scanning issue. However, I have added EntityScan to the Application and that didn't seem to help.
[RepositoryRestResource with spring-boot CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305553/repositoryrestresource-with-spring-boot-cli/25639754)

this question has an answer suggesting wrapping the repository in a controller class with RestController instead of using RepositoryRestResource. I can do that, but I don't want to write all the extra code, I would rather that RepositoryRestResource work instead.
[Clueless what I'm doing wrong setting up Spring Boot REST app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859279/clueless-what-im-doing-wrong-setting-up-spring-boot-rest-app)

project structure:

```
pom.xml  

src/main/java/com/springdataresttest/  
Application.java  
src/main/java/com/springdataresttest/entity/  
Thing.java
src/main/java/com/springdataresttest/repository/  
ThingRepository.java  

src/main/resources/  
application.properties  
hibernate.properties
```

postgres ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE thing
(
    id serial,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springdataresttest</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdataresttest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Application.java:

```
package com.springdataresttest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springdataresttest.entity"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Thing.java:

```
package com.springdataresttest.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "thing")
public class Thing {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ThingRepository.java:

```
package com.springdataresttest.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.springdataresttest.entity.Thing;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "things", path = "things")
public interface ThingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Thing, Integer>{

}
```

application.properties:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.ignored=/**

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/springdataresttest
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.platform=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/springdataresttest
hibernate.connection.username=postgres
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.schema=public
```

output from spring boot (notice that rest repository endpoints for "things" are not mapped)

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-08-23 14:57:51.118  INFO 1336 --- [           main] com.springdataresttest.Application       : Starting Application on LTW10me with PID 1336 (C:\Users\me.HQ\workspace\springdataresttest\target\classes started by me in C:\Users\me.HQ\workspace\springdataresttest)
2018-08-23 14:57:51.123  INFO 1336 --- [           main] com.springdataresttest.Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-23 14:57:51.233  INFO 1336 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6646153: startup date [Thu Aug 23 14:57:51 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-23 14:57:52.882  INFO 1336 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca53dd09] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-23 14:57:53.548  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-23 14:57:53.583  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-23 14:57:53.583  INFO 1336 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-08-23 14:57:53.593  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;"C:\Users\me.HQ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin;C:\cygwin64;C;\cygwin64\bin;";C:\Users\me.HQ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\me.HQ\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\me.HQ\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\eclipse;;.]
2018-08-23 14:57:53.709  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-23 14:57:53.709  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2481 ms
2018-08-23 14:57:53.876  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-08-23 14:57:53.881  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-23 14:57:53.881  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-23 14:57:53.881  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-23 14:57:53.886  INFO 1336 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-23 14:57:54.138  INFO 1336 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-08-23 14:57:54.720  INFO 1336 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-08-23 14:57:54.768  INFO 1336 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-23 14:57:54.793  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-08-23 14:57:54.944  INFO 1336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-08-23 14:57:54.947  INFO 1336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.username=postgres, hibernate.schema=public, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/springdataresttest, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver}
2018-08-23 14:57:55.015  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-08-23 14:57:55.155  WARN 1336 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
2018-08-23 14:57:55.168  INFO 1336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-08-23 14:57:55.188  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2018-08-23 14:57:55.193  INFO 1336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@64f16277
2018-08-23 14:57:55.716  INFO 1336 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-23 14:57:55.851  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-23 14:57:56.594  INFO 1336 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6646153: startup date [Thu Aug 23 14:57:51 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-23 14:57:56.653  WARN 1336 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-08-23 14:57:56.698  INFO 1336 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-08-23 14:57:56.703  INFO 1336 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-23 14:57:56.748  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-23 14:57:56.749  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-23 14:57:57.112  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-23 14:57:57.115  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-08-23 14:57:57.120  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-23 14:57:57.170  INFO 1336 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-23 14:57:57.180  INFO 1336 --- [           main] com.springdataresttest.Application       : Started Application in 6.496 seconds (JVM running for 6.954)
```

Comment: Where's your configuration setup to scan for repo's?

Comment: Its in Application.java. I'm using the built-in component scan from SpringBootApplication, and scanning for entities with EntityScan.